# Send select multiple values through post in jsp struts

Tags: jsp, struts, struts-1

Im building a web page in jsp where you can add, view, and delete authors, books and editorials.
In the addBook jsp its required to select the editorial of the book and the authors who wrote it.
The problem is in the struts action, where I try to catch the values sended through post.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <script>
    $(document).on("ready",function(){
        $("#bAdd").on("click", function(){
            var option=$("#authorsSelect option:selected").text();
            $("#saveAuthors").append('<option>'+option+'</option>');
            $("#authorsSelect option:selected").remove();
        });
        $("#bDel").on("click", function(){
            var option=$("#saveAuthors option:selected").text();
            $("#authorsSelect").append('<option>'+option+'</option>');
            $("#saveAuthors option:selected").remove();
        });
    });
   </script>
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><bean:message key="book.ins"/></h1>
    <form method="post" action="./insertBook.do?method=myAction1">
        title: <input type="text" id="title" name="title" required/> <br/>
        Year: <input type="number" id="yer" name="yer" required /><br/>
        Editorial: 
        <select  name="editorial">
            <logic:iterate name="editorialsList" id="editorial" scope="request">
                <option value="<bean:write name="editorial" property="id" />">
                    <bean:write name="editorial" property="name"/>
                </option>
            </logic:iterate>
        </select><br/>
        price: <input type="number" id="price" name="price" required /><br/>
        Select one or more authors:<br/>
        <select multiple id="authorsSelect" class="comboMultiple">
            <logic:iterate name="authorsList" id="autor" scope="request">
                <option value="<bean:write name="autor" property="id" />">
                    <bean:write name="autor" property="name"/> <bean:write name="autor" property="lName"/>
                </option>
            </logic:iterate>
        </select>
        <section id="botons" class="botons">
            <input type="button" id="bAdd" value=">>">
            <input type="button" id="bDel" value="<<">
        </section>
        <select multiple="multiple"  name="authorsSelect">
            <option> </option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="insert">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is where I retrive the information
    public class InsertBookAction extends DispatchAction {

```
public ActionForward myAction1(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
    String title = (String)request.getParameter("title");
    int year = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("year"));
    String editorial = (String)request.getParameter("editorial");
    int price = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("price"));
    String[] authors = request.getParameterValues("authorsSelect");
    for(int i=0;i<autores.length;i++){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,authors[i]);
    }
    return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);
}
}
```

In the line
      String[] authors = request.getParameterValues("authorsSelect");
Im getting a null value, can someone give me a hint at what im doing wrong please

Comment: You should never ever call `request.getParameterValues`... This is an answer. You are welcome.

Comment: @RomanC so how do i get the information?

Comment: Use default stack of interceptors, values will be populated automatically.

Comment: you have authorsSelect in two place in the form; one as Id with value and other has class with empty option; when form is sent; only the one with name="authorsSelect" will be sent to the mapping.You can check the value sent to your myAction1 class via web console ->network.

Comment: You have tagged to the wrong tag, the old framework doesn't use interceptors, but it's using beanutils to populate actionform.